# Create a report from google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, report

I have a [Google Sheets file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FdKkAYiV83NPZ4nyksh73eGYaLtnbpvZ/view?usp=sharing) I use to enter data on different properties.
Each row in this file represents a single property.
If a certain property is of interest, I would like generate a report for it.

I need a functionality that will extract all data fields from a single row, and insert them in a new file (google sheets or preferably a Google Docs file) with a pre built format that would present the data nicely [like a report](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YY6eiOQ3MiDzmxZyF5_3lntRxghTiO7a/view?usp=sharing).

Thanking you in advance

Avi

Comment: You need to provide more details of what you have tried. Please take a look at [How do I ask a Good Answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You need to be clearer how you will use the report.  Part of it looks like a data entry screen.  Columns H and I are letting you set values for that property as Safe, near Public Schools, etc.  If this is really a report, these values should be pulled from your database.  If this is a data entry screen, to add details to a property already in your database, that will be more complicated.  Also, these files are in Excel format, so is there a reason you are asking for Google Sheets advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very preliminary answer, to see if this is the right direction.
See my [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S7RGOu0nmzA1N0aIpghq5L7fbkz9fHcwyw9aU255BCw/edit?usp=sharing).

This lets you select, in C3, which address you want a report on.  The fields shown in green change as you select a different address.  All of the report fields could be modified like this - you just need to point to which column in the Properties database contains the values.

Is this roughly what you were looking to achieve?

[image]

Comment: Thanks,

I didnt quite understand what you did.
But I have managed using Vlookup to creat a row that always presents the requested property based on the property nu,ber incerte into a designated Cell,  and then simple copy and past of cells into a google sheets document.